# Chaining Callback Functions through a Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I don't want to preload my images at the same time anymore, I want to load them one after each other. Until now I did it like this:

```
for (var i = current; i < current + 5; i++) {
    images[i].load();
}
```

So I began to think how to use callbacks to load them sequentially: I can pass a callback to `load(callback)`, which will be called after one image has been loaded. So I can also just do it like this and they will be loaded after each other:

```
images[current].load(function(){
    images[current + 1].load(function(){
        images[current + 2].load(function(){
            images[current + 3].load(function(){
                images[current + 4].load();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This works, but I would love to transform it into a loop. I can't twist my head in a way to achieve this. Can you help?

---

I can only provide an example of my `load(callback)` method, because it is too long:

```
load = function(callback){
    // do preloading things and simulate load event:
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback.apply(this);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Here's a fiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/ajuc7g1q/1/

Comment: Post `.load` implementation.

Comment: Please .load implementation here as said above.

Comment: I posted an example of my load function and a fiddle to test it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it recursively:

```
var call_chain = function(){};

for(var i = current + 5; i >= current; i--){
    (function(f, index){
        call_chain = function(){
            images[index].load(f);
        };
    })(call_chain, i);
}

call_chain();
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a recursive function?

```
function loadImages(){
  var images = [img1, img2, ...];
  loadImage(images);

}

function loadImage(images){
  if(images.length){
      images.shift().load(function(){
          loadImage(images);
      });
  }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mvk4wtxh/)**

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't always want to load all of the images, but only about five starting from a given index. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ajuc7g1q/1/

Comment: Clean solution, but a minor technical point.  This isn't recursive, as there is only onc instance of `LoadImage` on the stack at a time.  Recursive specifically means there is something to return back *to*.